# show data from sqlite to recyclerview using recyclerview adapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

i am making an application where data is being saved in the database.i am lacking in displaying the data in the recyclerview using recyclerview adapter.don't know what code should be written. please check.

here is my files: MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView applist;
    ArrayList<Guides> guides;
    GuideAdapter adapter;
    GuideDB guideDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        guideDB = new GuideDB(this);

        guides = new ArrayList<>();

        applist = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.app_list);
        applist.setHasFixedSize(true);
        applist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new GuideAdapter(this,guides);
        applist.setAdapter(adapter);

        try {
            Cursor cursor = guideDB.getGuides("SELECT * FROM GUIDE_LIST");
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                int guide_id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String post_tile = cursor.getString(1);
                String post_desc = cursor.getString(2);
                String post_address = cursor.getString(3);
                byte [] post_image = cursor.getBlob(4);

                Guides g = new Guides(guide_id,post_tile,post_desc,post_address,post_image);
                guides.add(g);}
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}



    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add){

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PostActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**PostActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ImageButton mSelectImage;
    public EditText mPostTitle;
    public EditText mPostDesc;
    public EditText mPostAddress;
    public Button mSubmitbtn;
    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST= 1;
    GuideDB guideDB;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);


        guideDB = new GuideDB(this);
        mSelectImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);
        mPostTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleField);
        mPostDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descField);
        mPostAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressField);
        mSubmitbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);


        mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });
        mSubmitbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                if(!mPostTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !mPostDesc.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !mPostAddress.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,50,outputStream);
                    byte[] byteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();

                    try {
                        guideDB.addGuide(mPostTitle.getText().toString(),
                                mPostDesc.getText().toString(),
                                mPostAddress.getText().toString(),byteArray
                        );
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }

            }
        });

}


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri mimageUri = data.getData();
           try {
               InputStream inputstream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(mimageUri);

               bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputstream);
               mSelectImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

           }catch (FileNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}

        }
    }

}
```

**GuideDB.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;

/**
 * Created by 291 on 14.12.2017.
 */

public class GuideDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private  static final int DATABASE_VERSION= 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME= "guide_db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "GUIDE_LIST";
    private static String GUIDE_ID = "guide_id";
    private static String GUIDE_TITLE = "guide_title";
    private static String GUIDE_DESC = "guide_desc";
    private static String GUIDE_ADDRESS = "guide_address";
    private static String GUIDE_IMG = "guides_image";

    public GuideDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + GUIDE_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"
                + GUIDE_TITLE + "TEXT"
                + GUIDE_DESC + "TEXT"
                + GUIDE_ADDRESS + "TEXT"
                + GUIDE_IMG + "BLOB" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void addGuide (String title,String desc,String address,byte[] image){
        SQLiteDatabase gdb = getWritableDatabase();

        try
        {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO GUIDE_LIST VALUES(NULL,?,?,?)";
            SQLiteStatement statement = gdb.compileStatement(sql);
            statement.clearBindings();
            statement.bindString(1,title);
            statement.bindString(2,desc);
            statement.bindString(3,address);
            statement.bindBlob(4,image);
            statement.execute();


        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }

    public Cursor getGuides(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase gdb = getReadableDatabase();
        return gdb.rawQuery(sql,null);

    }
}
```

**GuideAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by 291 on 14.12.2017.
 */

public  class GuideAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GuideAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context ctx;
    private ArrayList<Guides> guidelist;

    public GuideAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Guides> guidelist) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.guidelist = guidelist;
    }

    @Override
    public GuideAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.guide_row,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GuideAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Guides guides = guidelist.get(position);
        holder.psttitle.setText(guides.getPost_title());
        holder.pstdesc.setText(guides.getPost_desc());
        holder.pstaddres.setText(guides.getPost_address());

        byte [] postimg = guides.getPost_image();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(postimg,0,postimg.length);
        holder.pstimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return guidelist.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView pstimg;
        public TextView psttitle;
        public TextView pstdesc;
        public TextView pstaddres;
        public int id;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            pstimg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            psttitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            pstdesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            pstaddres = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_address);
        }
    }
}
```

**Guides.java**

```
public class Guides {
    private int guide_id;
    private String post_title,post_desc,post_address;
    private byte [] post_image;



    public Guides(int guide_id, String post_title, String post_desc, String post_address, byte [] post_image) {
        this.guide_id = guide_id;
        this.post_title = post_title;
        this.post_desc = post_desc;
        this.post_address = post_address;
        this.post_image = post_image;


    }

    public int getGuide_id() {
        return guide_id;
    }

    public void setGuide_id(int guide_id) {
        this.guide_id = guide_id;
    }

    public String getPost_title() {
        return post_title;
    }

    public void setPost_title(String post_title) {
        this.post_title = post_title;
    }

    public String getPost_desc() {
        return post_desc;
    }

    public void setPost_desc(String post_desc) {
        this.post_desc = post_desc;
    }

    public String getPost_address() {
        return post_address;
    }

    public void setPost_address(String post_address) {
        this.post_address = post_address;
    }

    public byte[] getPost_image() {
        return post_image;
    }

    public void setPost_image(byte[] post_image) {
        this.post_image = post_image;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ugurcangursen.guideappsqlite.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/app_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="10dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_post.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ugurcangursen.guideappsqlite.PostActivity">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_btn" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/titleField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageSelect"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_outline"
        android:hint="Post Title..."
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/descField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleField"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_outline"
        android:hint="Post Description..."
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addressField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descField"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_outline"
        android:hint="Adres..."
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="SUBMIT POST"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

guide_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Başlık" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            tools:text="Açıklama" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            tools:text="Adres" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not reviewing all the code you have posted. However, it does appear that you are setting the adpater with an empty source (guides), so it would then display nothing.

The following version of the `onCreate` method may result in the data being displayed

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    guideDB = new GuideDB(this);

    guides = new ArrayList<>();

    applist = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.app_list);
    applist.setHasFixedSize(true);
    applist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    //adapter = new GuideAdapter(this,guides); //<<<< MOVED
    //applist.setAdapter(adapter);  //<<<< MOVED

    try {
        Cursor cursor = guideDB.getGuides("SELECT * FROM GUIDE_LIST");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            int guide_id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String post_tile = cursor.getString(1);
            String post_desc = cursor.getString(2);
            String post_address = cursor.getString(3);
            byte [] post_image = cursor.getBlob(4);

            Guides g = new Guides(guide_id,post_tile,post_desc,post_address,post_image);
            guides.add(g);}
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    adapter = new GuideAdapter(this,guides); //<<<< MOVED
    applist.setAdapter(adapter);  //<<<< MOVED
}
```